# Azure Resource Manager REST API Create virtual directory

Tags: c#, rest, azure-resource-manager

I am creating virtual directory in a virtual application using Azure Resource Manager REST API with HttpClient. After authentication I am doing a PUT request. Below is the code.

```
client.PutAsJsonAsync(requestUri,
new
{
properties =
new
{
virtualApplications = new
{
virtualPath = "/",
physicalPath = "site\\wwwroot",
preloadEnabled = false,
virtualDirectories = new
{
virtualPath = "/Abdul",
physicalPath = "site\\Abdul"
}
}
}
}).Wait();
```

The code is executed successfully. But virtual directory is not created. Am I using the right format?

Comment: So the response status code is 200 but no virtual directory being created, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly status code is 200 OK.